# Dapr Components not configured with docker compose

Tags: c#, docker, dapr

I have a c# application using Dapr and docker-compose
here is my docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"

services: 
  ##### Begin Infra #######
  
  #### Postgres #####
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: "dapr_prostgres"
    restart: always
    hostname: "postgres_server" 
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "mysecretpassword"
    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d 
    ports:
      - 5460:5432
    networks:
      - calendar_my-dapr-network
      
  ##### Zipkin #####
  zipkin:
    container_name: "dapr_zipkin_service"
    image: "openzipkin/zipkin:2.23.2"
    ports:
      - 9412:9411
    networks: 
      - calendar_my-dapr-network
  
  ##### Redis #####
  redis:
    container_name: "dapr_redis_service"
    image: "redis:6.2-alpine"
    command: [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    networks:
      - calendar_my-dapr-network
  #### End Infra #####
    
  ##### API & DAPR Sidecar #####
  calendarapi:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./src/APIs/Calendar.Api/Dockerfile
    depends_on: 
      - redis
      - zipkin
      - db
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "85:80"
    networks:
      - calendar_my-dapr-network

  calendarapi_dapr:
    image: "daprio/daprd:1.10.0"
    command:
      [
        "./daprd", 
        "--app-id", "calendar-service",
        "--app-port", "80",
        "--config", "/dapr/calendar-config.yaml",
        "--resources-path", "/dapr/components",
        "--log-level","debug"        
      ]
    volumes:
      - "./dapr:/dapr"
    depends_on:
      - calendarapi
    network_mode: "service:calendarapi"
    env_file:
      - .env
      
networks:
  calendar_my-dapr-network:
    driver: bridge
```

when I look at the logs for the daprd container I see
When I run docker compose up the logs show

time="2023-06-13T15:30:22.3665235Z" level=debug msg="found component. name: Calendar-Pub-Sub, type: pubsub.redis/v1" app_id=calendar-service instance=39b3db2d5f64 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.10.0

2023-06-13T15:30:22.366891500Z time="2023-06-13T15:30:22.3666076Z" level=debug msg="found component. name: calendar-secret-store, type: secretstores.local.file/v1" app_id=calendar-service instance=39b3db2d5f64 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.10.0

2023-06-13T15:30:22.366920200Z time="2023-06-13T15:30:22.3666275Z" level=debug msg="found component. name: calendar-statestore, type: state.redis/v1" app_id=calendar-service instance=39b3db2d5f64 scope=dapr.runtime type=log ver=1.10

but when I try to use the statestore or any other component it give me an error

```
public async Task SaveStateAsync(string stateStoreName,string key, T data, Dictionary<string, string>? metaData=null, CancellationToken ct=new())
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Preparing to save state for {Key} {Data}",key, data);
        await _daprClient.SaveStateAsync(stateStoreName,
            key, data,
            metadata: metaData, cancellationToken: ct);
        _logger.LogDebug("Saved state for {Key} {Data}",key, data);
    }
```

Dapr.DaprException: State operation failed: the Dapr endpoint indicated a failure. See InnerException for details.
---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="FailedPrecondition", Detail="state store is not configured")
at Dapr.Client.DaprClientGrpc.MakeSaveStateCallAsync[TValue](String storeName, String key, TValue value, String etag, StateOptions stateOptions, IReadOnlyDictionary2 metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---